# Ударения в фамилиях

Tags: фонетика

Есть ли какие-то закономерности расставления ударений в русских фамилиях? Например, композитор БородИн, но одновременно существует фамилия БорОдин, или разночтение в ударении ИвАнов- ИванОв.
Или тут просто нужно знать каждый конкретный случай?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверняка сказать, как та или иная фамилия звучит и где в ней ставится ударение, может только владелец-носитель этой фамилии. 
Да, правила об ударении в фамилиях есть, они очень пространные и интересны сами по себе, но в них лучше не заглядывать, поскольку они в основном состоят из исключений из этих самых правил.