# Ива́нов vs. Ивано́в - в чем разница?

Tags: этимология, орфоэпия, фамилии

Есть такая известная русская фамилия Иванов («на которых вся Россия держится»).

Есть 2 версии произношения:

1. *Ивано́в* — c ударение на `О` — более частая.
2. *Ива́нов* — ударение на `А` — редкая.

Так вот в чем разница? Видимо есть какие-то различия в происхождении фамилий или это некое эстетство ставить ударение на `А`?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4083/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85

Comment: Бармалей! Убраны оценочные «более традиционные и менее», чтобы не бросить тень на плетень и исключить отход от главного в вопросе — место ударения.

Comment: гипертолерантность детектед :)

Answer (score 3):

То, что приведено ниже, обсуждалось на нашем сайте (см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426261/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/426268#426268)) и было раскритиковано. Но все-таки, для полноты картинки, цитирую здесь:

> Даже самая простая и самая распространенная русская фамилия Иванов вызывает затруднения. Дело в том, что в XIX веке в среде образованных людей было принято ударение ИвАнов. Именно так произносится эта фамилия в драме Чехова, так же звучит фамилия писателя Всеволода Иванова. В произведении В. Саянова «Небо и земля» имеется такое разъяснение различной постановки ударения в этой фамилии: «Вот хотя бы армию взять: солдат – обязательно ИванОв, а офицер, хотя и десятый, а все-таки ИвАнов». После революции на смену устаревающему ударению Иванов приходит более демократическое – Иванов, которое является общеупотребительным и сегодня.